# MATLAB: how to generate all possible coalition-formations within M*M matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary

Assume that, there are 'M' objects aiming to form coalitions together. I need to know how to exhaustively generate all possible formations of coalitions using an M*M binary matrix given the following properties:

1- The elements of main diagonal are set to 1 (each object is in the same coalition with itself)

2- The matrix is symmetrical (being in the same coalition for two objects is a mutual relationship)

3- if objects (i,j) are in the same coalition, and (j,k) are in the same coalition, thus (i,k) are in the same coalition as well.

A simple formation of the coalitions with 4 objects is given by this example:

[image: example1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use another data structure which is easier to generate, then convert it to the matrix you want. Use a list with the coalition ids, where the coalition id is the minimum of all object ids. For your example this would be `[1 2 1 1]`. Using this data structure it's easier to describe a generator.

For each object you have the choice between joining one of the existing coalitions opened by objects with a smaller id or to open a new coalition.

There is probably no vectrorized solution, to implement this use a recursion or dynamic programming.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I still think solution to the original representation of problem could be more straightforward.

Comment: I don't think so, because the representation you described requires constrains to be checked. This might be very difficult to implement without brute forcing.